# How to convert array objects to just elements without the [] wrapper in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have encountered a problem in my code where I have to pass a 2D array to a function. The function works normally when I pass the values as `[[166, 1692], [463, 1506], [113, 1572], [490, 1480]]`, but what I am receiving from another piece of code is this: `[array([498]), array([1568])], [array([242]), array([1688])]]`. I want to convert this format to the previous one. I want then in x,y format and I have tried many ways to convert back and forth and it does not work. I have to remove that "array" wrapper and also the "[]" wrapper around every element. Is there any way to do this? Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE**: Thank you for all the answers. The answer by Ayoub Zarou works as expected. Thank you once again.

Comment: can you show what you tried ?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) you can use `.tolist()` to convert your array to a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing :

```py
np.array(x).reshape((len(x), -1)).tolist()
```

where `x` is your list

Comment: Happy coding , you could approve the answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you are dealing with numpy arrays, "yourlist"`.tolist()` should do the trick.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
a = list(a)
print(a)
# outputs [array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])]

print(np.array(a).tolist())
# outputs [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

# If you are removing the brackets, you can simply flatten() it.
a = np.array(a).flatten()
print(a.tolist())
# outputs [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and telling where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```py
from numpy import array
a = [array([498]), array([1568]), array([242]), array([1688])]
b = array(a).tolist()
print(b)
```

Output is:

```sh
[[498], [1568], [242], [1688]]
```

---

Another solution which gives the same output:

```py
import numpy as np
a = [array([498]), array([1568]), array([242]), array([1688])]
b = list(map(np.ndarray.tolist, a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pick the first value out of each array with a list comprehension:

```
from numpy import array    
inlist = [[array([1]), array([2])], [array([3]), array([4])], [array([5]), array([6])]]
# form of inlist: [[array([1]), array([2])], [array([3]), array([4])], [array([5]), array([6])]]
outlist = [[a[0], b[0]] for a,b in inlist]
```

Which gives you

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```